# `mount` works, `mount -a` not - same config, two drives

Tags: mount, ssd, fstab

I have two external ext4 SSD drives connected on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS system.

```
$ blkid
...
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ext01" UUID="4f384179-5f1d-41b6-9cb0-a9cc1cbc15b4" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="62bb06c9-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="ext02" UUID="11f26526-81e1-4095-9d19-f68a81429c5d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0ab49ec5-01"
```

I can mount both drives manually, but `ext02` will fail when I use `mount -a`.
`ext01` just works.
Both drives are formatted the same way.

Manually:

```
$ mount UUID=11f26526-81e1-4095-9d19-f68a81429c5d /media/ext02
```

Works also when I replace UUID with `/dev/sdb1`.
I can also access (read/write) `ext02` when mounting manually.

But `mount -a` failes:

```
# /etc/fstab
...
# ext01
UUID=4f384179-5f1d-41b6-9cb0-a9cc1cbc15b4 /media/ext01 ext4 defaults,uid=997,gid=997,umask=0002 0 0

# ext02
UUID=11f26526-81e1-4095-9d19-f68a81429c5d /media/ext02 ext4 defaults,uid=997,gid=997,umask=0002 0 0
```

Results in:

```
$ mount -a    
mount: /media/ext02: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

dmesg output:

```
[184455.373774] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.1.110\video
[184461.506283] CIFS: VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[184461.513035] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -113
[258435.838017] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=997" or missing value
[258628.679450] EXT4-fs (sdb): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[258646.809446] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=997" or missing value
[258704.194711] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=997" or missing value
[258842.780459] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[259170.295136] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=997" or missing value
[259327.735905] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=997" or missing value
```

The uid 997 exists, it also works with `ext01`.

Any ideas how to get this work?

Comment: `uid=997,gid=997,umask=0002` are not valid mount options for ext4, why would one expect this to work?

Comment: Nice, was new to me. Anyway, I didn't get the error for the first mount, so that's really confusing =)

Comment: If external drive you may want nofail. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654952/consistent-auto-mount-of-external-hard-drive & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437500&p=13935156#post13935156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I changed the owner and the group (based on the uid and gid I wanted) of the target folder `/media/ext*` after mounting it manually and removed the `uid`, `gid` and `umask` options from `fstab`.

When the drives are umounted, the ownership is `root`.
When mounted, it shows the correct owner.